# How do I get my PiGlow to work

Tags: python-2.7

After following the steps on this page https://github.com/Boeeerb/PiGlow. I did everything correctly and when i try to run the test.py file it says this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last) :
   File "test.py" , line 9, in <module>
      piglow = PiGlow()
    File "/home/pi/piglow/piglow.py" , line 30,in _init_
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have tried rebooting, and trying it multiple times

Comment: what happens when you `ls /home/pi/piglow/piglow.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem, it was because I hadn't enabled i2c on my raspberry pi.

These lines are directly from the README file in the piglow examples available from pimoroni, but they got everything working:

========== README.md ===================
Enable the i2c driver modules by editing the modules config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Then either add or ensure the following lines are at the end of the file:

```
i2c-dev
i2c-bcm2708
```

You may also need to ensure the driver modules are not blacklisted by editing the blacklist config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf
```

Ensure that if the following two lines exist in that config file that you comment them out by adding a # sign at the start of the line. So:

```
blacklist spi-bcm2708
blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

...should become...

```
# blacklist spi-bcm2708
# blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

Then we install the i2c libraries and Python support:

```
sudo apt-get install python-smbus
```

Then reboot your Pi!

========== README.md ===================

Hope that helps!