# Python code PiGlow on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python

After following the steps on this page https://github.com/Boeeerb/PiGlow. I did everything correctly and when i try to run the test.py file it says this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last) :
   File "test.py" , line 9, in <module>
      piglow = PiGlow()
    File "/home/pi/piglow/piglow.py" , line 30,in _init_
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have tried rebooting, and trying it multiple times. When I ls is it says that it is there

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get my PiGlow to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805252/how-do-i-get-my-piglow-to-work)

Answer (score 0):

$sudo modprobe i2c-dev

I found this --- worked for me -----

Now you should be able to see the i2c ports listed in your /dev/ directory

```
$ls /dev/i2c*
```

You should see /dev/i2c-0 and /dev/i2c-1 listed. To be able to use these ports you need to give yourself permission to access them.

```
$sudo chmod o+rw /dev/i2c*
```

Now your i2c ports will be ready for you to use. You will have to run the modprobe and chmod commands every time you login to activate the ports and apply the permissions. If you wish to automate this process so the commands are run every time you log in then you can edit /etc/rc.local and add the commands in.